# workflow: exclude migrations files from checkIn in TFS?

Tags: tfs, version-control, migration, workflow

We have 3 main Repoes branches in TFS(Root"PROD",QA,Development"DEV") we have some issue with our migration files are out of sync sometimes between 3 Repoes. just I want to ask should we exclude migrations files from checkIn and only checkIn configuration files if you are merging from dev to QA  ? specially between Dev and QA ?

Note: sometime will have many child branches from Dev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a **.tfignore file**.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-sg/library/ms245454(v=vs.140).aspx

```
######################################
# Ignore .cpp files in the ProjA sub-folder and all its subfolders
ProjA\*.cpp
# 
# Ignore .txt files in this folder 
\*.txt
#
# Ignore .xml files in this folder and all its sub-folders
*.xml
#
# Ignore all files in the Temp sub-folder
\Temp
#
# Do not ignore .dll files in this folder nor in any of its sub-folders
!*.dll
```

Another way is to use check in policy (**Forbidden Patterns Policy**) in the [TFS Power Tools](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/site/search?f%5B0%5D.Type=SearchText&f%5B0%5D.Value=Team%20Foundation%20Server%20Power%20Tools&f%5B1%5D.Type=RootCategory&f%5B1%5D.Value=tools&f%5B1%5D.Text=Tools&f%5B2%5D.Type=SubCategory&f%5B2%5D.Value=teamdevelopment&f%5B2%5D.Text=Team%20Development) , how to add check in policy please refer the [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181459.aspx) from MSDN.